# how to use out-file with a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite 
ForEach($list in $web.Lists) 
{

if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
{
    Write-Host $list.Fields
    if($list.Fields.ContainsField("marking") -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Host "found" $list.Title
    }
}
} | Out-File test.txt
```

I have this code, which doesn't work due to `write-host` outputting to command line so obviously it won't write to the file.
How can I make it so it doesn't output to the command line but just outputs all the items found to the text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `Out-File` with the `-Append` switch after the lines you want to write, and take out the`Write-Host`.

Comment: Do I not write the file I want it to output to?

Comment: Yeah, like "found" $list.Title | Out-File test.txt -Append

Answer (score 0):

This would be a cleaner way to do it and probably faster. You're not going to get the carriage
return you're getting in your script after $list.Fields but I suspect you don't want that anyway

```
$doclibraries = (Get-SPWeb http://mysite).Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq 'DocumentLibrary'}
foreach ($library in $doclibraries) {
    $line = $library.Fields
    if ($Line.ContainsField('marking')) {
        Add-Content -Value "$line found $($library.title)" -Path test.txt
    }
}
```